# How to take multiple inputs in Typeahead?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

How do I allow user to type multiple values in typeahead textbox like, he types ph and the suggestions pops up php and he selects it, next he types da and the suggestion databases pops up and he selects that too. So in the end the text in my inputbox looks like

> php, databases

How should I go about achieving this effect?

I tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var getTags = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(d){ return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.result)},
        queryTokenizer: function(d){ return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d)},
        remote: {
            url: 'query=plughere',
            wildcard: 'plughere'
        }
    });
    getTags.initialize();
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: getTags.ttAdapter(),        
    });

    $('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocomplete', function(evt, item) {
        f = $('#hemo').val();
        $('#hemo').val(f + ", ");
    });

});
```

I programmed my server to only consider the last word after comma.

Here hemo is the id of my textbox. As soon as I select databases it removes already typed word before it. So if I select php first then I select databases it removes php from the textbox and adds databases to it.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f350hgn6/)

Comment: you are looking for taginput. Something like this http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct that the second argument on that bind event outputs the value based from this [link](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300) then you should use it like this.

```
 $('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocomplete', function(evt, item) {
    f = $('#hemo').val();
    $('#hemo').val(f + item.value + ", ");
 });
```

**Update**

After looking in your fiddle, I thought you were going to have another textbox where your selected values are put there.

I'm not sure if that's possible what you want but as a work around you can have all those selected values in a different textbox instead.

Sample: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pL62yq2/)

Comment: Nope it still resets the textbox and now it even adds undefined to each word. Reading through your link.

Comment: Ok, do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: Added the JSfiddle to the question but it won't work without the server right? I am using flask to process these requests.

Comment: I am making the search bar just like in stackoverflow bro. So I can't have multiple textboxes. I went through the typeahead docs and even I couldn't find anything relevant so I am currently hacking through typeahead.bundle.js around line 2167